# How to use Tabbed Navigation

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am using using sidebar with router (home page) in react js application.The page navigation from sidebar is working fine as per my requirement.I would like to know how to use "Tabbed Navigation".(to view multiple page in same time via tabbed).

Comment: It depends a bit on how you are setting up your tabs. Are you using a package for that? Do you want your tabs to be different routes like `home/tab1` or you can use hash `home#tab1`. Also are you using react-router?

Comment: yes, I am using built-in admin template  for react core-ui (https://coreui.io/demo/3.1.0/#main.html)